# How to select two frames from a video? opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to select two frames from a video. The following is my code, but it can only select the first frame. Could someone help me? Thanks~

```
long frameOne = 2130;
long frameTwo = 2160;
long currentFrame = frameOne;
bool stop = false;
while(!stop)
{
    if(!capture.read(frame))
    {
        cout << "Failed to read the video!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // select the first image
    if(currentFrame == frameOne)
    {
        frame1 = frame;
    }
    if(currentFrame == frameTwo)
    {
        frame2 = frame;
    }

    if(currentFrame>frameTwo)
    {
          stop = true;
    }
    currentFrame++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get the frames without watching the video you can just jump to the frame you are looking for with:

```
cv::Mat frame,frame1,frame2; 
capture = cv::VideoCapture(videoFname);
if( !capture.isOpened( ) ) 
{
    std::cout<<"Cannot open video file";
    exit( -1 );
}
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frameOne);
capture >> frame;
frame1 = frame.clone();
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frameTwo);
capture >> frame;
frame2 = frame.clone();
```

It works with OpenCV 2.4.6, I am not sure for previous versions.

Comment: Wa,wonderful! I used OpenCV2.4.3, and it worked now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am sorry that I saw you message just now and I accepted! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that

```
long currentFrame = frameOne;
```

should be

```
long currentFrame = 1;
```

Code:

```
long frameOne = 2130;
long frameTwo = 2160;
long currentFrame = 1;
bool stop = false;
while(!stop)
{    

    if(!capture.read(frame))
    {
        cout << "Failed to read the video!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // select the first image
    if(currentFrame == frameOne)
    {
        // it needs a deep copy, since frame points to the static capture mem
        frame1 = frame.clone();
    }
    if(currentFrame == frameTwo)
    {
        frame2 = frame.clone();
    }

    if(currentFrame>frameTwo)
    {
          stop = true;
    }
    currentFrame++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried your method. But the result is the same. So, I think the problem is caused by the if condition. Anyway, thank you!